# LINQ. Группировка по коду в Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, словари

SQL возвращает простой набор данных:

```
GoodId  Quantity    CenaZak CenaRoz SkladId
3       1190        369,66  455,00  0001
3       954         341,28  420,00  0002
25      5688        320,72  394,00  0001
25      11895       329,37  391,00  0002
35      143         381,61  469,00  0001
36      303         699,72  861,00  0001
```

эта модель описана классом:

```
    public class Price
    {
        public int GoodId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal CenaZak { get; set; }
        public decimal CenaRoz { get; set; }
        public string SkladId { get; set; }
    }
```

На входе имеем `List<Price>`

Как получить объект описывающий вот такую структуру:

```
{
    "3": [
           { "quantity":1190, "cenaZak":369.66, "cenaRoz":455, "SkladId":"0001"},
           { "quantity":954, "cenaZak":341.28, "cenaRoz":420, "SkladId":"0002"}
         ]
   .........
 }
```

где 3 это GoodId

Для удобства создал еще класс с моделью:

```
    public class PriceItem
    {
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal CenaZak { get; set; }
        public decimal CenaRoz { get; set; }
        public string SkladId { get; set; }
    }
```

т.е. на выходе должен быть `Dictionary<GoodId, List<PriceItem>>`
но вместо имени ключа `GoodId` должно быть значение

---

проект Web API на Core 3.1
контроллер :

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<KeyValuePair<string, PriceItem[]>>>> PerOrder([FromQuery] string Token)
```

группирую:

```
var dat = dt.GroupBy(a => a.GoodId).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Select(k => new PriceItem()
                {
                    Quantity = k.Quantity,
                    CenaZak = k.CenaZak,
                    CenaRoz = k.CenaRoz,
                    Supplier = k.Supplier,
                    StoreId = k.StoreId,
                    StoreName = k.StoreName,
                    StoreAddress = k.StoreAddress
                }).ToArray());

                return dat;
```

SQL возвращает набор данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вызове контроллера получаю ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается при преобразовании в Dictionary берется только первая строка и дублируется по кол-ву строк у каждого GoodId, как поправить код чтобы вывести все строки у GoodId

Comment: `var result = коллекция.GroupBy(x=>x.GoodId);`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ к сожалению это решит задачу, нужно что-то еще, и именно это пока до меня не доходит

Comment: @rawman, почему это не решит задачу? В любом случае есть метод [`ToDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Grundy , первая проблема в том что группировка предполагает использование какой-нибудь агрегирующей функции, Min, Max, Avg или что-то еще. как такую функцию применить к сложному объекту, а не к простому полю ?

Comment: @rawman, _группировка предполагает использование какой-нибудь аггрегирующей функции_ - это с чего бы? Ты пробовал код из первого комментария?

Comment: @Grundy , хорошо, что тогда не так здесь :
```var dat = dt.GroupBy(a => a.GoodId).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => new List<PriceItem>() { new PriceItem { Quantity = p......... } }); ``` 
вот в такой конструкции нет доступа к элементам объекта PriceItem

Comment: @Grundy , вторая проблема в том что в качестве ключа должно быть не имя, а значение из GoodId

Comment: @rawman, _хорошо, что тогда не так здесь_ - вроде все так, кроме лишнего на мой взгляд GroupBy. Про _в качестве ключа должно быть не имя, а значение из GoodId_ - не понял, у тебя это значение и используется в качестве ключа. Ну и для значений тебе скорее всего надо было вызывать `p.ToList()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = new List<Price>();
...
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.GoodId)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
            x => x.Select(z => new PriceItem() { CenaRoz = z.CenaRoz /*.и т д..*/})
            .ToArray());
```

Comment: Спасибо, почти то что нужно, получил массив объектов:
  ```{
    "Key": "3",
    "Value": [
      {
        "quantity": 1190,
        "cenaZak": 369.66,
        "cenaRoz": 455,
        "SkladId": "0001",
      }
    ]
  },```
как теперь 3 поставить вместо Value ?

Comment: @rawman, у тебя какие-то странные результаты. Как именно ты смотришь значение?

Comment: @Grundy , у меня проект Web API на Core 3.1, этот ответ я вижу в Swagger при выполнении запроса к данному контроллеру

Comment: @rawman, ооок, добавь в вопрос, как у тебя описан контроллер и что именно ты возвращаешь.

Comment: @rawman у вас в вопросе написано `на выходе должен быть Dictionary<GoodId, List<PriceItem>>` - я вам дал именно то, что вы запросили. Измените ваш метод, чтобы он возвращал `Task<Dictionary<string, PriceItem[]>>`

Comment: @tym32167 , получилось что нужно. огромное спасибо.

Comment: @rawman пожалуйста. Галочка слева от вопроса.

Comment: @tym32167 , сразу не доглядел, почему-то в объекты PriceItem берется только первая запись и дублируется по кол-ву строк. как это победить ?
``` "3": [
    {
      "quantity": 2,
      "cenaZak": 0,
      "cenaRoz": 461,
      "skladId": "2276"
    },
    {
      "quantity": 2,
      "cenaZak": 0,
      "cenaRoz": 461,
      "skladId": "2276"
    },
    {
      "quantity": 2,
      "cenaZak": 0,
      "cenaRoz": 461,
      "skladId": "2276"
    }
  ]```

Comment: @rawman в моем коде такого быть не может. У вас либо проблема с вашими данными, либо вы мой код неверно переписали. В любом случае, вы не показали ни того, ни другого.

Comment: @tym32167 , добавил подробное описание со скриншотами, посмотри пожалуйста, что с этим можно сделать ?

Comment: @rawman что такое dt? Откуда оно берется?

Comment: @tym32167 , var dt = await db.Price
                    .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC [dbo].[ApiPricePerOrderForSite] ClientId = {client.Id}")
                    .ToListAsync();
dt имеет тип List<Price>

Comment: поставьте точку останова и проверьте, что вам вернуло вот это `[dbo].[ApiPricePerOrderForSite]`

Comment: @tym32167 , так и есть, не правильно мапится результат SQL запроса в List<Price>, почему так может происходить? куда копать? все поля перепроверил, по названиям, по порядку следования, что я пропустил ?

Comment: @tym32167, огромная спасибо за помощь. победил. проблема была в том что ключ в модели был прописан на одно поле, а в данном случае он составной. добавил в контекст ```modelBuilder.Entity<Price>().HasKey(x => new { x.StoreId, x.GoodId });```  и все заработало как надо !!!!

Comment: @rawman если вам мой ответ помог, отметьте его галкой.